# Three switches, one light

Tags: logic, state, xor, circuit-diagram

I'm not 100% certain that stack overflow is the correct exchange to post this; if it isn't please let me know.

I have three switches, all corresponding to one light. When ANY one of the switches are flipped, the light should go from ON to OFF or OFF to ON. For this implementation, I'm only allowed to use XOR gates.

After drawing out a truth table, it becomes clear that the light is in the ON state only when one of the switches are in the UP position, or all three of the switches are in the UP position (the light is initially off with all three switches in the down position). I was able to deduce the new state of the light for the one-switch UP case by simply XOR'ing each pair of switches (3 pairs). However, I'm not sure about how to find out how to differentiate between all three switches in the UP position (which corresponds to the light being ON), and all three switches in the DOWN position (light is off). From what I understand, it is impossible to create an AND gate from XOR gates, so I'm stuck here..

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe http://electronics.stackexchange.com would be the better place for this as it's hardware, not software.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say the three switches are A, B and C : you could try `A XOR B XOR C`.

Comment: Wow that was much easier than I was making it to be.. thanks!